Update Multiple Reports in Power BI
At the moment, there are 14 reports pbix stored in the backoffice where I work. Whenever visual updates are made from the source dashboard, I encounter the challenge of manually publishing each report online, needing to enter them one by one and publish them within the workspace. Recently, I came across the realization that the Power BI API offers a solution to this issue by enabling direct publication to the desired workspace. Is this the sole method available for accomplishing this task?
I truly need to automate this process of publishing these reports; it typically takes me around half an hour to publish them all.
Power BI Update Report Content in Python, didn't work.
